# Identifying a Belkin KVM Switch Cable

Tags: cable, keyboard-video-mouse

I have 2 of these cables lying around that come with the used rack that I purchased. I am trying to identify these cables and what KVM switch they connect to.

[Belkin KVM switch cable](https://imgur.com/a/MlQHQ6A)

Comment: Just to confirm - each of the cables is one big rectangle at one end, two VGA/USB at the other?

Comment: Right. so the kvm side splits into 2 x VGA+USB pigtail

Comment: I believe this might be a Parallel SCSI cable.

Comment: Looks like the second or third cable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_connector#/media/File:Scsi-connectors.jpg

Comment: The 2nd cable in the picture you linked does have 50 pins like mine. It could be a SCSI connector but I am inclined to believe it's still goes into a KVM since it has a VGA+USB pigtail on the other end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like the Belkin OmniView Dual-Port USB KVM Cable  SKU:F1D9401-06 :

https://www.belkin.com/uk/omniview-dual-port-usb-kvm-cable/P-F1D9401.html

[image: Belkin OmniView Dual-Port USB KVM Cable]

Compatible with the Belkin OmniView PRO3 KVM switch

https://www.belkin.com/uk/omniview-pro3-usb-ps2-kvm-switch/F1DA116Zea.html

[image: Belkin OmniView PRO 3]

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. It might be the cable for this kvm switch. I'll confirm it and then accept this answer.